# Zeros of polynomials over $\mathbf{Z}$ can be rational?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, definition

> Any rational zero of a polynomial of the form
> $$f=X^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1X+a_0\in\mathbf{Z}[X]$$ is an
> integer.

How can a rational number be a zero of a polynomial over the integers? Isn't it true by definition, in this case, that $f$ can be "evaluated" only on integers since it is a polynomial over $\mathbf{Z}$: i.e.
$$f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$$
is defined only for $x\in\mathbf{Z}$. Surely, then, the expression "$f(x)$" must be nonsense for $x\in\mathbf{Q}$. What am I missing?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[X] \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Comment: Where do you encounter a problem if you attempt to define $f\left(\frac 12\right)$, say?

Comment: For example, $x=\frac{1}{2}\in\mathbb Q$ is a rational zero of the polynomial $f(x)=2x-1\in\mathbb Z[x]$. However this is possible as the leading coefficient of that polynomial (being $2$) is not invertible in the ring $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: "polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$" means the coefficients are from $\mathbb{Z}$. It doesn't talk about the evaluation of any sort.

Comment: Think of Intro Calculus where you look at integer polynomials like $x^3 - 3x +4$ interpreted as functions on the real numbers.

Comment: Surely you have met the statement that $\mathrm{i}$ is a root of $x^2+1$. This polynomial lies in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and its root isn't even in $\mathbb{R}$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integers $\mathbb{Z}$ are special cases of the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ which are special cases of the reals $\mathbb{R}$ which in turn are just special complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. So it does make perfect sense to talk about e.g. $\pi^2 + 2 \pi - 42$. Yes, the coefficients are taken to be real (or complex), just that they happen to be integers.

It is perfectly fine to restrict oneself to just working with integers (or rationals, or reals), but polynomials are normally considered over $\mathbb{C}$, in large part because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, i.e., each non-constant polynomial has a zero, all polynomials of degree $n$ have $n$ zeros (counting multiplicities). Working in $\mathbb{C}$ is all-around nicer.

Also note that when talking e.g. about the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the $x$ is just a placeholder, that happens to behave like a ring element, but is *not* an integer. The focus is on the coeficients, which happen to compose like they were in a polynomial with integer (or whatever) indeterminate $x$.

Answer (score 2):

As @Ajay Kumar Nair notice, polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ means the coefficients are from $\mathbb{Z}$. It doesn't talk about the evaluation of any sort.
In this case, since you are considering monic polynomials, the result will follow if you consider $p/q \in \mathbb{Q}$ a zero of the polynomial with $gcd(p,q)=1$ and derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of the set $\mathbb{Z}(X)$ are just formal power series. They do not directly correspond to functions defined over a given domain. The statement in question implies that you are considering $f\in\mathbb{Z}(X)$ as functions $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

The integers $\mathbb{Z}$ are special cases of the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ which are special cases of the reals $\mathbb{R}$ which in turn are just special complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. So it does make perfect sense to talk about e.g. $\pi^2 + 2 \pi - 42$. Yes, the coefficients are taken to be real (or complex), just that they happen to be integers.

It is perfectly fine to restrict oneself to just working with integers (or rationals, or reals), but polynomials are normally considered over $\mathbb{C}$, in large part because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, i.e., each non-constant polynomial has a zero, all polynomials of degree $n$ have $n$ zeros (counting multiplicities). Working in $\mathbb{C}$ is all-around nicer.

Also remember that when you are considering e.g. the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients, your $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the $x$ is just a placeholder, it is *not* an integer.